# Cleanup on error in CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake to build my application and launch its tests.

One of my tests must acquire some resource (say, it creates a file), and therefore it needs to release the resource upon completion.
My problem is that when the test fails, the resource is not released.

My cmake command basically looks like this:

```
add_custom_target(acquire_test_release
    COMMAND acquire_resource
    COMMAND perform_test.py
    COMMAND cleanup_resource
)
```

Whenever `perform_test.py` returns non-zero, `cleanup_resource` is not called.

My question is the following:
How can I perform the cleanup operation even when my test fails, while retaining the failure condition and error code from my test (the target should still fail)?

I tried putting my test in a `||` (eg, `COMMAND perform_test.py || true`), but then I lose the return code and the failure condition, while obscuring the target.

Comment: In your concrete case, as fast workaround you may use `COMMAND perform_test.py || ( cleanup_resource && false )`. But it is better to create a script (shell/python/whatever) which implements tests running and call this script with *COMMAND* option. CMake is bad for *general* scripting with return codes and conditions.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution would work, albeit I would lose the precise return code of `perform_test.py`? So a script to perform all three operations (acquire, test, release) and return the return code of the test operation seems mandatory? I think its sad that CMake doesn't offer finer control over target completion...

Comment: You can remove the output folder of the test. That will trigger a reconfigure and rebuild, but might be good enough.

Comment: @usr1234567 Just to be clear, removing the output folder of the test is not my concrete case, just an example among several situations. I'm interested by a general solution to the problem of cleanup on failure with CMake. Tsyvarev's suggestion that CMake can't do that natively and to use a script is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your concrete case, as a fast workaround you may use

```
COMMAND perform_test.py || ( cleanup_resource && false )
```

In that case you will lose presize code returned by `perform_test.py` (only zero/non-zero division remains).

But it is **better to write a script** (shell / python / whatever) which implements proper tests running scenario. Then you may use given script with a single *COMMAND* option.

---

When concerned about **build actions** (as opposite to *configure* actions), CMake is **bad for *general* scripting**. And a sequence of `COMMAND` options executed until fail is the most CMake provides.

Remember: CMake doesn't perform *building* by itself, this functionality is  leveraged to other build tool. Even in Makefile' receipt it is difficult to implement conditional logic, but CMake tends to support multiple build tools.

However, CMake *script mode* (`cmake -P`) is relatively rich. If you want *cross-platform* test running scenario without additional prerequisites like python, you may easily write script on CMake.